# Comment author name = user name by default?

Tags: 6, users, comments

My website can only be accessed by authenticated users. How can I automatically make the author's name the user's name without giving users the option to input anything else in the name field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the permissions table, located at admin/user/permissions you will find a permission that allows you to disallow users from changing their own name it is called **change own username**

If you are manually creating users, this should work well for you because they will have the name you created for them and they will not be able to change it. However, if the users create their own accounts, one option for you to consider is the [Real Name Module](http://drupal.org/project/realname)

Answer (score 1):

Well, correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I know (and based on a check I've just done in D6 sandbox) logged-in users do not have option to change their name, they see their username displayed in normal text instead of form textfield. So that's exactly the behavior you're looking for?

Comment: Uh... yeah, sorry abou that, I think because I was logged in with user-1, I was under a different impression...